# Will apps fail to download if I'm still on iOS6?

Tags: ipad, software-update

I am still running iOS 6 on my iPad.

I have several apps that are failing to download right now (error message is "unable to download update at this time") and I'm wondering if it could be because I am not on the latest OS?

I have done the following troubleshooting:

- Reset home network
- Reset the iPad
- Tried to tap on the app needing updates so that it triggers it to start
- Verified that my account works fine
- Verified free space (10+ gb)

I'm not sure what other troubleshooting I can do, so I thought I'd see here if my OS version was a potential problem or what else I should look into next.

Comment: What do you mean by 'fail to download'? What error message do you get? Are you downloading from iTunes sync or from the App Store?

Comment: The exact error message is "unable to download update at this time" there's no further details or error code. And I'm trying through the app store.

Comment: I think it had to do with network issues. We are about 20' from the router. Even though it shows full strength at this distance, it was resolved when I brought the device much closer to the router (5')

Comment: So the problem is solved? Could you add the solution as an answer (and self-accept it), this will make it easier for others in a similar situation to find the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out to be a network issue. 
Even though I had reset my home router, it came down to how far away from the router I was. I guess the iPad couldn't get a stable enough connection to meet the needs of the download (even though the wifi icon on the ipad showed full strength). Moving closer to my wireless router resolved the problem.